# Is Stack Exchange Music too picky?

Tags: discussion

I saw [this question today](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/22044/i-really-need-to-know-the-guitar-chord-to-this-song-how-do-i-do-it) and wondered if it might be best if we just try to answer more questions like this.

Stack Overflow gets a ton of questions that never get answered. It makes sense to be careful and remove questions that are off topic there.

But Stack Exchange Music seems to have more answerers than questions.

Is it really a good idea to close these as off topic when we need questions? Is there a format we could answer this question in? Wouldn't music learners be more attracted to ask questions and participate in the community if they could just get helpful answers to these questions, even though it may not be have broad or generally applicable use?

Answer (score 6):

It is a good idea to close questions which are off topic or out of scope. We do have regular discussions (on all the Stack Exchange sites) as to what should be in and out of scope.

Here, we have lots of questions on analysis of songs, however analysis of a specific song, unless there is some special reason, is going to be out of scope as it is unlikely that anyone else will ever want the answer.

This makes sense when you realise what Stack Exchange is: the resource for people to come to with a question.

An answer that helps hundreds or thousands of individuals is of much more value than one that helps only one.

Also, Music is like most beta sites in having many answerers - we are currently trying to tip over the hump into wider awareness, which will bring more people/more questions/graduation to full site etc.

Comment: I'm in favor of widening the scope, but I agree that these questions should be out of scope. There are enough of tab resources out there in order to justify that this QA site does not become another one.